# Problem with highcharts + vue.js : specific chart for measurements

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web, highcharts, arguments

I'm working with Highcharts and Vue.js, and have multiple charts on my page. For now, I'm able to display the data on every chart without any problems. However, I want to set (for example) a special title for a specific graph.

I have the following files:

StockChart.vue (this file is shared part of the code for all charts)

```
<template>
    <highcharts class="stock" :constructor-type="'stockChart'" :options="stockOptions"></highcharts>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props : [
            'data'
        ],
        data () {
            return {
                stockOptions: {
                    rangeSelector: {
                        selected: 'all',
                        buttons: [{
                            type: 'hour',
                            count: 6,
                            text: '6h',
                        }, {
                            type: 'hour',
                            count: 24,
                            text: '24h'
                        }, {
                            type: 'day',
                            count: 7,
                            text: '7d'
                        }, {
                            type: 'month',
                            count: 1,
                            text: '1m'
                        }, {
                            type: 'month',
                            count: 3,
                            text: '3m'
                        }, {
                            type: 'all',
                            text: 'All'
                        }]
                    },
                    series: this.data,
                    title :{
                        //text : this.data[0].myTitel,
                        text : this.data[0].myTitel
                    }


                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            data (newValue) {
                this.stockOptions.series = newValue
      //        this.stockOptions.title = newValue[0].myTitel.toString()
                console.log(newValue[0].myTitel)
                this.stockOptions.data = newValue
            },
        }
    }
</script>
<style scoped>
    .stock {
        width: 70%;
        margin: 0 auto
    }
</style>
```

and the second file called `Temperature.vue`, where sending the request for series to my database, and return it in order to display on the specific chart.

```
import Influx from 'influx'
    import moment from 'moment'
    import NProgress from 'nprogress'
    import StockChart from '../components/StockChart.vue'
    import credInflux from "../constants/influx"

    var newPath;                                                    //new path taken from the URl
    var oldPath;                                                    //old path taken from the URL


    const client = new Influx.InfluxDB({
        database: credInflux.database,
        host: credInflux.host,
        port: credInflux.port,
        protocol: credInflux.protocol,
        username: credInflux.username,
        password: credInflux.password
    });

    export default {
        props : [
            'sectorName'
        ],
        name: 'temperature',
        components: {
            StockChart,
        },
        mounted () {
            newPath = this.sectorName                               //save the new path to know witch page to load
            console.log("sectorname : " + this.sectorName)
            NProgress.start();

            this.loadTemperatureFloorData(this.createQueryTemperatureFloor(newPath));
            this.loadBatterySensorData(this.createQueryBattery(newPath));
            this.loadTemperatureSensorData(this.createQueryTemperatureSensor(newPath));

            this.dualData(this.createQueryBattery(newPath))

            oldPath=newPath;
        },

        // done when before the page updated
        beforeUpdate() {
            this.reloadPage()                                   // function to reload the page
        },


        methods : {
            /**
             * reload de page when the user switch the room
             */
            reloadPage : function(){
                newPath = this.sectorName
                if(newPath !== oldPath){
                    console.log(newPath)
                    location.reload()
                }
            },

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            /**
             * return the query in function of the path (sectorname) in real life this is the illuminance_value
             * @param page
             * @returns {string}
             */
            createQueryTemperatureFloor : function(page){
                let returnQuery
                switch(page.toString()){
                    case "Télécabine":
                        returnQuery = 'select "payload_fields_Illuminance_value" from mqtt_consumer WHERE topic = ' + "'" + 'ayent_monitoring/devices/ambient_sensor_2/up' + "'"
                        break;
                    case "Pralan":
                        returnQuery = 'select "payload_fields_Illuminance_value" from mqtt_consumer WHERE topic = ' + "'" + 'ayent_monitoring/devices/70b3d57ba0000bd0/up' + "'"
                        break;
                    case "Pro de Savioz":
                        returnQuery = ''
                        break;
                    default :
                        console.log("returnQuery : switch default case")
                        break;
                }

                return returnQuery
            },

            /**
             * return the query in function of the path (sectorname) in real life this is the Air temperature_value
             * @param page
             * @returns {string}
             */
            createQueryTemperatureSensor : function(page){
                let returnQuery
                switch(page.toString()){
                    case "Télécabine":
                        returnQuery = 'select "payload_fields_Air temperature_value" from mqtt_consumer WHERE topic = ' + "'" + 'ayent_monitoring/devices/ambient_sensor_2/up' + "'"
                        break;
                    case "Pralan":
                        returnQuery = 'select "payload_fields_Air temperature_value" from mqtt_consumer WHERE topic = ' + "'" + 'ayent_monitoring/devices/70b3d57ba0000bd0/up' + "'"
                        break;
                    case "Pro de Savioz":
                        returnQuery = ''
                        break;
                    default :
                        console.log("returnQuery : switch default case")
                        break;
                }

                return returnQuery
            },

            /**
             * return the query in function of the path (sectorname) in real life this is the battery voltage_value
             * @param page
             * @returns {string}
             */
            createQueryBattery : function(page){
                let returnQuery
                switch(page.toString()){
                    case "Télécabine":
                        returnQuery = 'SELECT "payload_fields_Battery voltage_value" from mqtt_consumer WHERE topic = ' + "'" + 'ayent_monitoring/devices/ambient_sensor_2/up' + "'"
                        break;
                    case "Pralan":
                        returnQuery = 'SELECT "payload_fields_Battery voltage_value" from mqtt_consumer WHERE topic = ' + "'" + 'ayent_monitoring/devices/70b3d57ba0000bd0/up' + "'"
                        break;
                    case "Pro de Savioz":
                        returnQuery = ''
                        break;
                    default :
                        console.log("returnQuery : switch default case")
                        break;
                }

                return returnQuery
            },
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            /**
             * load temperature of the floor data from the database
             * @param paramQuery
             */
            loadTemperatureFloorData: function(paramQuery) {

                console.log("query : " + paramQuery)

                Promise.all([
                    client.query(paramQuery),
                ]).then(parsedRes => {
                    const mutatedArray = parsedRes.map( arr => {
                        this.lastTemperatureFloorValue = arr[arr.length-1]['payload_fields_Illuminance_value'].toFixed(2); //to fixed: fix number of digit


                        return Object.assign({}, {

                            name: "Temperature au sol", // name on the chart
                            turboThreshold:60000,
                            tooltip: {
                                valueSuffix: ' °C'
                            },
                            data: arr.map( obj => Object.assign({}, {
                                x: (moment(obj.time).unix())*1000,
                                y: obj['payload_fields_Illuminance_value']
                            }))
                        });

                    });
                    this.series_temperatureFloor = mutatedArray;
                    NProgress.done();
                }).catch(error => console.log(error))
            },

            /**
             * load temperature of the sensor data from the database
             * @param paramQuery
             */
            loadTemperatureSensorData: function(paramQuery) {

                console.log("query : " + paramQuery)

                Promise.all([
                    client.query(paramQuery),
                ]).then(parsedRes => {
                    const mutatedArray = parsedRes.map( arr => {
                        this.lastTemperatureSensorValue = arr[arr.length-1]['payload_fields_Air temperature_value'].toFixed(2); //to fixed: fix number of digit


                        return Object.assign({}, {

                            name: "Temperature sensor", // name on the chart
                            turboThreshold:60000,
                            tooltip: {
                                valueSuffix: ' °C'
                            },
                            data: arr.map( obj => Object.assign({}, {
                                x: (moment(obj.time).unix())*1000,
                                y: obj['payload_fields_Air temperature_value']
                            }))
                        });

                    });
                    this.series_temperatureSensor = mutatedArray;
                    NProgress.done();
                }).catch(error => console.log(error))
            },

            /**
             * load Battery data from the database
             * @param paramQuery
             */
            loadBatterySensorData: function(paramQuery) {

                console.log("query : " + paramQuery)
                Promise.all([
                    client.query(paramQuery),
                ]).then(parsedRes => {
                    const mutatedArray = parsedRes.map( arr => {
                        this.lastBatteryValue = arr[arr.length-1]['payload_fields_Battery voltage_value'].toFixed(2); //to fixed: fix number of digit


                        return Object.assign({}, {

                            name: "Niveau de batterie", // name on the chart
                            turboThreshold:60000,
                            tooltip: {
                                valueSuffix: ' V'
                            },
                            data: arr.map( obj => Object.assign({}, {
                                x: (moment(obj.time).unix())*1000,
                                y: obj['payload_fields_Battery voltage_value']
                            }))
                        });

                    });
                    this.series_battery = mutatedArray;
                    NProgress.done();
                }).catch(error => console.log(error))
            },


            /**
             * load Battery data from the database
             * @param paramQuery
             */
            dualData: function(paramQuery) {

                console.log("query : " + paramQuery)
                Promise.all([
                    client.query(paramQuery),
                ]).then(parsedRes => {
                    const mutatedArray = parsedRes.map( arr => {
                        this.dualValue = arr[arr.length-1]['payload_fields_Battery voltage_value'].toFixed(2); //to fixed: fix number of digit


                        return Object.assign({}, {
                            myTitel : 'dual test',
                            name: "Niveau de batterie", // name on the chart

                            turboThreshold:60000,
                            tooltip: {
                                valueSuffix: ' V'
                            },
                            data: arr.map( obj => Object.assign({}, {
                                x: (moment(obj.time).unix())*1000,
                                y: obj['payload_fields_Battery voltage_value']
                            }))
                        });

                    });
 //                   console.log(mutatedArray)
                    this.series_dual= mutatedArray
 //                   this.series_dual =[{
 //                       name: 'Rainfall',
 //                       type: 'spline',
                      //  yAxis: 1,
 //                       data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
 //                       tooltip: {
 //                           valueSuffix: ' mm'
 //                       }
 //                   }],

                    NProgress.done();
                }).catch(error => console.log(error))
            },


        },





        data () {
            return {


                series_temperatureFloor : [{
                    turboThreshold:60000,
                    data: [],

                }],

                series_temperatureSensor: [{
                    turboThreshold:60000,
                    data: [],

                }],

                series_battery : [{
                    turboThreshold:60000,
                    data: [],

                }],


                series_dual:[{
                    turboThreshold:60000,
                    data:[],


                }],

                lastTemperatureFloorValue:"",
                lastTemperatureSensorValue:"",
                lastBatteryValue:"",

                dualValue:"",

            }

        },






    }



</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

As you can see, in the function `dualData: function(paramQuery)`, I'm trying to pass the argument `myTitel` (specific title for only this chart), and after that, in the `Stockchart.vue`, trying to retrieve this value, but it doesn't work. Anybody has an idea, why?

Do I need to create and work with a specific `Stockchart.vue` for each chart?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason of not using computed property?
I defined a static data within the parent component, passed those options through child `props`, and changing the `myTitel` property (little remark here, this property should actually be called `myTitle`) every one second in parent component. Looks like everything works fine.

Live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-vue-demo-7xxg2?file=/src/App.vue